# jQuery insertBefore, Apend for dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please take a look at code, it is working, it should add just one p tag, but for some reason it is inserting several p tags. P tags are not dynamically created, but some of the content in the p tag is created dynamically(just for info, if it is important).

```
 jQuery("div.content").on("click", ".add", function (e) {

        var ptag = jQuery('p.test-me');
        ptag.insertBefore('.main-content');

        return false;
    });
```

I would just like to insert one p tag(not several) on click before other p tag with class .main-content.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `var ptag = jQuery('p.test-me').eq(0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var ptag = jQuery('p.test-me').eq(0);
ptag.insertBefore('.main-content');
```

Comment: Hi, tnx, that was the problem, I wasn't thinking. Long day :(

Comment: Why would you bother creating a variable, when you could simply chain the methods: `jQuery('p.test-me').eq(0).insertBefore('.main-content');`?

Answer (score 0):

In your code as you are referring `p elements` with class name `.test-me` there might be possibility of retrieving multiple elements if you have p more than one p elements with that class name. As you said it is appending multiple p elements, it is confirmed that there are multiple elements with the class name `.test-me`. If you do not want more than one element to be appended, and very sure about what element to be append just use `id` instead of class name, else just get first element of element list.

```
    // with id

    var ptag = jQuery('#id-of-p').clone().attr('id','');

    //  with className but first element

    var ptag = jQuery('.test-me').first(); or .eq(0);


    // with id, but should have .test-me class name, then only append?

    var ptag = jQuery('#id-of-p.test-me').clone().attr('id','');
```